# Reparameterization of hyperprior distribution

Tags: probability, bayesian, change-of-variable

I'm reading about Bayesian data analysis by Gelman et al. and I'm having big trouble interpreting the following part in the book (note, the rat tumor rate $\theta$ in the following text has: $\theta \sim Beta(\alpha, \beta)$):

> Choosing a standard parameterization and setting up a ‘noninformative’
> hyperprior dis- tribution. Because we have no immediately available
> information about the distribution of tumor rates in populations of
> rats, we seek a relatively diffuse hyperprior distribution for $(\alpha, \beta)$.
> Before assigning a hyperprior distribution, we reparameterize in terms
> of $\text{logit}(\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}) = \log(\frac{\alpha}{\beta})$ and $\log(\alpha+\beta)$, which are the logit of the
> mean and the logarithm of the ‘sample size’ in the beta population
> distribution for $θ$. It would seem reasonable to assign independent
> hyperprior distributions to the prior mean and ‘sample size,’ and we
> use the logistic and logarithmic transformations to put each on a
> $(-\infty, \infty)$ scale. Unfortunately, a uniform prior density on these newly
> transformed parameters yields an improper posterior density, with an
> infinite integral in the limit $(\alpha+\beta) \rightarrow \infty$, and so this particular prior
> density cannot be used here.
>
> In a problem such as this with a
> reasonably large amount of data, it is possible to set up a
> ‘noninformative’ hyperprior density that is dominated by the
> likelihood and yields a proper posterior distribution. One reasonable
> choice of diffuse hyperprior density **is uniform on** $(\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}, (\alpha+\beta)^{-1/2})$, which when multiplied by the **appropriate Jacobian** yields the following densities on the **original scale**,
>
> $$p(\alpha, \beta) \propto (\alpha+\beta)^{−5/2},$$
>
> and on the **natural transformed scale**:
>
> $$p\left(\log\left(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\right), \log(\alpha+\beta)\right)\propto \alpha\beta(\alpha+\beta)^{−5/2}.$$

My problem is especially the bolded parts in the text.

> **Question (1):** What does the author explicitly mean by: "**is uniform on** $(\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}, (\alpha+\beta)^{-1/2})$"
>
> **Question (2):** What is the **appropriate Jacobian**?
>
> **Question (3):** How does the author arrive into the **original and transformed scale** priors?

To me the book hides many details under the hood and makes understanding difficult for a beginner on the subject due to seemingly ambiguous text.

P.S. if you need more information, or me to clarify my questions please let me know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured the solution out myself so I'm gonna share it here if anyone is going to bump into the same part in Gelman's book (pages 110-111).

**Answer (1):**

The author simply means by this that
 $$p\left(\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta},
 \;(\alpha+\beta)^{-1/2}\right)=\text{constant}\propto 1.$$

**Answer (2):**

When the author talks about "appropriate Jacobian" he's talking about the **determinant of the Jacobian matrix** in the [change of variables formula for density functions](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/157):

$$p(\phi)=p(\theta)\,{\color{blue}{\det\left(\frac{d\theta}{d\phi}\right)}}$$

**Answer (3):**

The author simply applies the change of variables formula two times. We know that $$p(\gamma, \delta) = p(\gamma(\alpha, \beta),\, \delta(\alpha, \beta))=p\left(\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta},
 \;(\alpha+\beta)^{-1/2}\right)=\text{constant}\propto 1.$$

If we denote $\theta=(\gamma, \delta)$ and $\phi=(\alpha, \beta)$, then:

$$\det\left(\frac{d\theta}{d\phi}\right)=\left|\begin{array}{cc} \frac{d\gamma}{d\alpha} & \frac{d\gamma}{d\beta} \\ \frac{d\delta}{d\alpha} & \frac{d\delta}{d\beta}\end{array}\right|=\left|\begin{array}{cc} \frac{\beta}{(\alpha+\beta)^2} & -\frac{\alpha}{(\alpha+\beta)^2} \\ -\frac{1}{2(\alpha+\beta)^{3/2}} & -\frac{1}{2(\alpha+\beta)^{3/2}}\end{array}\right|=-\frac{1}{2(\alpha+\beta)^{5/2}}.$$

From change of variables formula we get:

$$p(\alpha, \beta) = \underbrace{p\left(\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta},
 \;(\alpha+\beta)^{-1/2}\right)}_\text{= constant $\propto \;1$}\cdot \left(-\frac{1}{2(\alpha+\beta)^{5/2}}\right)\propto (\alpha+\beta)^{-5/2},$$

and there it is, i.e. the prior in original scale.

For the alternative scale, by using change of variables in exactly the same manner:

$$p(\alpha, \beta) = p\left(\log\left(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\right), \log(\alpha+\beta)\right)\,\det\left(\frac{d\theta}{d\phi}\right),$$

where this time $\gamma(\alpha, \beta) = \log\left(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\right)$ and $\delta(\alpha, \beta) = \log(\alpha+\beta)$. For the Jacobian determinant we get:

$$\det\left(\frac{d\theta}{d\phi}\right)=\left|\begin{array}{cc} \frac{d\gamma}{d\alpha} & \frac{d\gamma}{d\beta} \\ \frac{d\delta}{d\alpha} & \frac{d\delta}{d\beta}\end{array}\right|=\left|\begin{array}{cc} 1/\alpha & -1/\beta \\ (\alpha+\beta)^{-1} & (\alpha+\beta)^{-1}\end{array}\right|=\frac{1}{\alpha\beta},$$

so we get:

$$\underbrace{p(\alpha, \beta)}_\text{$\propto\, (\alpha+\beta)^{-5/2}$} = p\left(\log\left(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\right), \log(\alpha+\beta)\right)\,\frac{1}{\alpha\beta},$$

or

$$ p\left(\log\left(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\right), \log(\alpha+\beta)\right) \propto \alpha\beta(\alpha+\beta)^{-5/2}.$$